# About fibers and bijection

Tags: notation, terminology

> If $T = \{q\}$ consists of a single element of $B$, $f^{−1}(T)$ is called
>   the fiber of $f$ over $q$. Thus a function $f : A \to B$ is a bijection if it has nonempty fibers over all elements of $B$ (that is: $f$ is surjective), and these fibers are in fact singletons (that is: $f$ is injective).

I am trying to understand the quote above.

Define $f: A \to B$. Let $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and $B = \{4, 5, 6\}$. Suppose $T = \{4\}$ and $f^{−1}(T) = \{1\}.$ So, then $\{1\}$ is the fiber of $f$ over $4.$ Does it make sense so far?

$f$ is surjection if there's one-to-one correspondence between $\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}$ and $4, 5, 6.$

$f$ is injection by definition of fiber?

Also, is there more suggestive term than "fiber"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:A\to B$ be a map.

**Prop1** Suppose the fibers of $f$ are nonempty. Then $f$ is surjective.

*Proof:* Let $b\in B$. We need to show that there exists $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. Well, the fibers are nonempty, so there exists $a\in f^{-1}(b)=\{x\in A\mid f(x)=b\}$. Therefore, $f(a)=b$ as required.

**Prop2** Suppose every fiber of $f$ contains at most one element. Then $f$ is injective.

*Proof:* We need to show that if $f(a)=f(a')$ then $a=a'$. Well, for $b=f(a)=f(a')$, we have that both $a,a'\in f^{-1}(b)$. As $f^{-1}(b)$ contains no more than one element we must have $a=a'$.

For your final question, I think `fiber' is pretty suggestive. If $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is the map $f(x,y)=x$, what do the fibers $f^{-1}(x)$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$ look like?

Comment: Consider $f(x) = 2x$ and let $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$. Then $f(A) = \{2, 4, 6\}$. Then is $A$ fiber of $f(A)$?

Comment: @Kyle fibers are the preimages of points. So $f^{-1}(2)=\{1\}$, $f^{-1}(4)=\{2\}$ and $f^{-1}(6)=\{3\}$ are the fibers of $f$.